# Get NSString out of ENNoteContent with Evernote Cloud SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote

I am new to Evernote SDK development and am using the evernote cloud SDK 2.0 as recommended by Evernote.

However, I am having trouble to get the NSString content out of the ENNoteContent object. I have tried the followings from searching online but none seems to work with the cloud sdk as I guess they are all for the old version of Evernote SDK...

**1 Using "convertENMLToHTML" method.**

According to [this](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/36673-en-note-content-is-not-displaying-properly-enml-to-html/) and [this](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios/blob/fa6f0bbf9bc2862c44cfaf1cfcc6588ae5aec585/SampleApp/NoteBrowserViewController.m), I could call convertENMLToHTML directly on an ENNoteContent object much like this `convertENMLToHTML:note.content`. However, in the cloud SDK, this resulted in an exception inside ENMLUtility that terminates the app because convertENMLToHTML is expecting an NSString as opposed to ENNoteContent and the first thing this function does is trying to call `[enmlContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]` which caused the exception if enmlContent is a pointer to ENNoteContent but not a pointer to NSString.

**2 Attempting to get _emml object out of the ENNoteContent object**

This [post](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/81500-getting-nsstring-of-ennotecontent/) has a quote of calling `[note.content enml]` but this again doesn't work with cloud sdk as object `enml` isn't defined in the interface.

Does anyone know how one can get an NSString out of ENNoteContent? I would expect this to be a very straightforward process but am surprised that I wasn't able to find anything that works for the Cloud SDK.

**3 Using generateWebArchiveData method**

Per Sash's answer below, I have also attempted to use the generateWebArchiveData method in the example from the cloud sdk. The code I have looks like this:

```
[[ENSession sharedSession] downloadNote:result.noteRef progress:^(CGFloat progress) {
} completion:^(ENNote *note, NSError *downloadNoteError) {
    if (note) {
        NSLog(@"%@", note.title);

        [note generateWebArchiveData:^(NSData *data) {
            NSString* strContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"test content %@", strContent);
        }];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading note contents %@", downloadNoteError);
    }
}];
```

However, strContent outputs "null" for a note that I have verified with legitimate content.

As a temporary hack, we added `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * emml;`
in ENNoteContent.h and removed the same line in ENNoteContent.m to get around this for now.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Technique #1 above is what you want, but as you discovered the enml property is private in the "default" SDK. Import the "advanced" header and you'll have access to note.content.enml. That is a string, and you can send it to convertENMLtoHTML if you prefer an HTML representation.

Do note that there is no "plaintext" string content for an existing note. You'll always see it as markup, and if you want to get rid of the markup, doing so is beyond the scope of the SDK-- how to do that depends very much on what the content you're dealing with looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out their samples included with SDK, seems like 
`-[ENNote generateWebArchiveData:]` will get you HTML `NSData` in the completion block

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Getting_Started.md#downloading-and-displaying-an-existing-note might also help

Comment: Thanks Sash. That's a good idea but unfortunately I don't think that works. I will update the main question with this test.